# Does wire gauge matter for speaker cable for a home stereo system?

Tags: electrical, audio

I'm planning an electrical installation at home and need to know what speaker cables to lay.

So far, neither the speakers nor the stereo amplifier have been selected, but I know that:

- The room is approximately 33 square meters large and has a high ceiling of 2.9 m.
- The stereo floor-standing speakers will be 8 m and 11 m from the amplifier.

Does the thickness/type of cable matter in this case?

Comment: As far as I know, speaker cables are even less standardized than telephone, which is less standardized than Ethernet, which is less standardized than mains (120V - 240V) wiring. In other words, pretty much anything goes. I would generally look for thicker wire rather than thinner, but hopefully an audio expert will give a real answer.

Comment: Are you an audiophile? Then go spend $50/foot (probably a significantly low price estimate these days) on high quality, oxygen free copper cable. Are you a normal person? Then go buy "speaker cable" at ~$1/foot like the rest of us (price may have gone up as everyone think their copper is _very_ special these days).

Comment: This _might_ fall under "Use, explanation, and history of music **technology, devices**, and media" at [musicfans.se]. Maybe migrate it there.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm definitely not audiophile, 0,001% loss in quality is not an issue for me.

Comment: This reminds me of the great debates a number of years ago which were finally settled (to my satisfaction) by someone doing blind testing between expensive large gauge oxygen-free copper and wire coat hangers twisted together in a string. _It didn't matter_. Use a gauge large enough to not introduce voltage drop at your run length and don't worry about it.

Comment: I had a similar argument with the sales guy at our local high end audio store. I said that so long as enough _digital_ info was making it from the player to the TV, the quality of the HDMI cable didn't really matter. It matters even less for a digital signal, the receiving end has to get a signal above a cutoff point to consider it a 1 and below it a 0. Doesn't matter how far above that point. In theory, it does matter more for analog signals, but, as noted, nobody can really tell...

Comment: @isherwood So what would be guage large enough? Or it depends...

Comment: It depends on your amp and speakers. Something like 16 ga. is usually plenty. I wouldn't use 18 or 22 for in-wall wiring.

Comment: Ok, so I need to narrow down selection of the hardware before laying down the cables.

Comment: See this in EE. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/13927/33670 DO NOT ask the question there, do not migrate the question there, but read that (and other) answers.

Comment: QED 79 strand speaker cable will be fine. Or you could go to somewhere like [elfadistrelec.pl](https://www.elfadistrelec.pl) and choose something from them. If the cable is going to be moved around, you want stranded, if it will rarely be moved, solid core will be OK as long as the terminals at both ends will accept it.

Comment: Are you going to be wiring directly from the amp to the speakers, or providing sockets in the walls so that short cables can be used from there to the speakers?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I thought about using sockets like this https://www.selby.com.au/av-distribution/wall-plates/1-speaker-wall-plate-wp1021.html so it both looks better, especially when speakers are not connected.

Comment: @dzieciou If using sockets at both ends, you could use ordinary 2.5 mm2 mains cable for the hidden wiring, then use short pieces of stranded speaker cable at each end. You can get fancy-looking banana plugs which are not expensive, if you like - there is no need to pay lots for them.

Comment: It's DC; it should be stranded. "Larger wire that isn't stranded will increase inductance, which will lead to increased impedance at higher frequencies." [Do expensive, "premium" speaker cables make a difference?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/do-expensive-premium-speaker-cables-make-a-difference)

Comment: @Mazura There should not be DC going to the speakers. For the same diameter, the inductance of the wire will be the same whether or not it is stranded. Are you thinking about the [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)? For copper at 10 kHz, it's about 0.65 m.

Comment: I forgot DC just makes a buzzing noise. Prob thinking of skin effect as to why they always said to use stranded for speaker wire, but that's negligible bunk too. Internet says use stranded because it's subject to vibrations and that it doesn't really matter if it's solid.

Comment: Just a sidenote: I had the same issue, my solution was to run an empty conduit from the (likely) place of the amp to the (likely location of) speakers. This way you can postpone selecting a cable until the actual equipment is selected. And it even provides an upgrade path if you decide to become a full-fledged audiophile

Comment: There's a large difference in musical enjoyment between a system equipped with 93-strand OxygenFreeWhatever and the cheapest Romex. If you buy the former, you'll have far less money left to spend on actual music on streaming, CDs, LPs, downloads, or whatever your chosen physical format is. Regardless of format, the Romex (of sufficient cross section, see the other quantative answers) will sound the same as the 93-strand snake-oil.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, it matters. It's very important for full-range speakers (ones with deep bass), and much less so for bookshelf satellites.

Wire gauge and length affect the *[damping factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_factor)*. In simple terms, this factor decides whether a speaker diaphragm, once it's set in motion, is free to bounce (at low DF) or only moves as the music permits.
It's calculated as [speaker impedance divided by (amplifier impedance+cable resistance)](https://us.kef.com/blogs/news/damping-factor-explained).

Damocles' answer addresses minimum gauge for tolerable voltage drop, but if you want good low-frequency sound, you also need a high damping factor. Low damping factor results in bass blending together into a loud hum - like cheap party speakers driven too loud (though there it's due to poor diaphragm  rigidity). High DF allows high-quality speakers, ones with rigid diaphragms, to produce firm brief punches, resembling a live drum.

DF=50 is considered the minimum for stage music. DF=20 is acceptable for public venues, like a cafe, where music is just background. Studio and home hi-fi sound aims for a DF of 50-100 or more. Metal and honeycomb woofers work best at very high DF, for paper it's less critical.

11 meters is a longer speaker cable run than most home setups. Using [4 mm² wire](https://www.bcae1.com/dampfact.htm) (11 gauge) and 4 Ohm, typical of floorstanders, will only get a DF=40. What I do in such situations is either get an even thicker wire - 6 mm² will do DF=55 - or double up widely available 4 mm² wire, to get DF=75.

The best way to double up, if you can't get 6-8 mm² wire, is to take two 22 m runs of 4 mm² wire (equal length for both speakers), find the middle, and braid the doubled-up cable. Strip insulation in the middle and connect the cable to the amplifier, without actually cutting it in half. Solder banana connectors to the other end, rejoining the cable. Needless to say, today, with online shopping, buying 8-9 AWG (6-8 mm²) cable outright is much easier than doubling up.

Don't worry if it's not the best-known brand; that only has a minor effect on sound, which some even question, while the impact of the damping factor is profound and well-measured.

In professional audio, to provide consistently high DF no matter how long the wire run, the speakers are usually active, i.e. the amplifier is inside the speaker cabinet. You might want to consider this option too, but 11 m is still OK for thick wires.

Comment: The Wikipedia numbers in Damocles' answer are not about safety -- for that, you would need to know the power levels involved. Those numbers are about resistance, with the gauges and maximum lengths selected to give a minimum damping factor of 20, where the wire resistance is no more than 5% of the speaker resistance. As you say, higher DF would be better (within limits).

Comment: This sounds like the "Audiophile" answer. For the common Joe, it's probably overkill. :shrug:

Comment: @FreeMan Depends on how you define "audiophile". I'd hazard a guess that anyone installing floor-standing stereo speakers in 2024 is likely concerned with sound quality. Muddy bass is very noticeable, and a bit of extra copper isn't a big expense. In a rock concert, you'll usually find active speakers with DF>100, which helps it sound clear even at high volume. For easy background listening, it's less important.

Comment: Speaking of audiophile options: Canare 4S12F, which will give DF=50 and is specifically designed for in-wall setup, is $10/meter. It gets a lot of praise and there's no need to go higher. Off-brand cables will be cheaper, but probably no less than $5 due to the price of copper.

Comment: @FreeMan Not really, much more like the sane answer. The audiophile answer would start to rave about how 1000-dollars-per-meter cable sounds so much better than everything else below it. :-)

Comment: @Therac I'd say anyone installing floor standing stereo speakers in 2024 is an audiophile :-) Common joe uses a separate subwoofer. I suspect you need to spend serious money on both the amp and speakers for floor standing to be the better option.

Answer (score 12):

The potential issue with a long run of thin wire is high resistance leading to signal degradation. A typical speaker is rated between 2 and 8 ohms, so as long as the resistance of the wire is small in comparison you'll be fine. The resistance of a wire is a product of its intrinsic properties (gauge and material) and its length. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_wire) gives this chart as a guide:

[image]

Since you haven't selected the speakers yet, you can prepare for the worst-case scenario and assume 2Ω. (They will probably be 8Ω in the end though). Then measure the distance of the cable run, and consult the chart.

Comment: Even at 8Ω, 18 gauge is a little too thin to go 10m. *"Ok, so I need to narrow down selection of the hardware before laying down the cables."* and have zero future proofing for something you're going to bury in a wall? - It's also nice when it's just arbitrarily bigger so that when you've twisted the end for the sixth time and five strands break off, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mazura  that's why conduit is a smart move for low voltage stuff...

Comment: @Mazura If you have to keep twisting the ends, perhaps adding ferrules, or using solid-core wire, or adding banana plugs would work out better. Or if the terminals are the screw-down type, fork terminal connectors could be added to the wire ends. It's got to be better than getting those strands making holes in your thumbs.

Comment: If there are two wires going to my speaker, should I take the sum of their lengths when consulting the table above?

Comment: @dzieciou no, that calculation is for a 2-wire cable.

Answer (score 7):

Stop by your local home improvement center, electrical supply house, home audio store, or other place that sells wiring and pick up enough "speaker wire" to make the runs you need.

Also, make sure that the wire is rated for in-wall installation. There are certain insulation materials that are rated for in-wall use, many are not.

Unless you're an audiophile who claims to be able to hear the sampling rate of a standard CD and finds it irritating, your speaker cable (even though delivering an analog signal) won't be significantly degraded on an 11m/33ft run.

It's probably more important that you keep the speaker cable away from any mains voltage electrical wiring than the actual wire you use for the audio signal.

If you have a couple of options for wire gauge and the price difference isn't significant and it makes you feel better, splash out a little extra cash for a heavier gauge.

---

Funny, this is getting down votes, but it *does* answer the OP's question. His question is about the length of the run, not the purity of the audio quality. As a matter of fact, the OP [specifically stated](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/290981/does-wire-gauge-matter-for-speaker-cable-for-a-home-stereo-system/290985#comment612641_290981) that he wasn't particularly worried about quality loss:

> @FreeMan I'm definitely not audiophile, 0,001% loss in quality is not an issue for me.

It seems everyone's voting this down because it's not the "audiophile purist's proper answer". Well, go spend $100/foot on expensive wire that makes you feel better.

This is 100% correct for the OPs desire.

*Oh noes, people don't like me and I've lost some pointz, whatever am I to do??*

Comment: LFT4 is the flame spread rating they look for in my area for code on in wall low volt wires.

Comment: Note that if you really want something cheap, there is nothing that says you _can't_ use NM as in-wall speaker wire :P

Comment: Is NM-B cheaper than speaker wire these days, @ThreePhaseEel? I haven't priced NN-B in the last 6 months, but the last batch I bought, I had to give my first-born's right leg for it...

Comment: This is simply untrue on every level. What's sold as "speaker wire" in most DIY stores will be 0.5mm2 at best. For 22m of cable (11m both ways) that's 0.8 ohms which is significant relative to the speaker impedance. DIY shops often also charge a mark-up for  "oxygen-free" snake oil too. And that's before we look at damping factors. This isn't audiophile level stuff, it's absolute basics of Ohm's Law. Please, everyone, don't think this answer reflects physical fact.

Comment: That may be the case, @Graham, but that's _NOT_ what the OP asked about.

Comment: @FreeMan The OP asked about laying something suitable for a home stereo system. Your answer does not produce results suitable for even a basic home stereo system. We're not talking audiophile here - your version would be noticeably worse on a $50 supermarket special.

Comment: I guess that makes this an opinion based question then...